# After upgrading from13.10 to 14.04 screen on a laptop doesn't work but

Tags: boot, multiple-monitors, display, 14.04

First my laptop CPU/GPU is Intel Celeron N2815 (Bay Trail) and I am in dual boot with windows 8.

I have upgraded from ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04 today through update manager. And after upgrading and after booting the only thing that happens is that screen doesn't show ubuntu logo for booting and that at some point it turns off. Also then I hear ubuntu sound when it comes to login screen. The screen doesn't turn on after that. (Also I have to tell you that I tried to install ubuntu 14.04 from USB and that there was the same problem. It asked me what I want to do (Try or install ubuntu) and it doesn't matter what option I selected the result was the same.)

Then I decided to try some stuf. First I tried to bootup with Ubuntu with Linux 3.11.0-19-generic. And it went well. The screen was working and everything was fine. Then I decided to try to hook my desktops screen on laptop via HDMI and right away it worked. Both screens were on and I had two screens. So I went in System Settings -> Displays and there saw 3 screens. Built-in Display, my secondary desktop display and unknown display. In 13.10 I had to turn of Unknown Display because all the workspaces were size of built-in display + Unknown Display so I didn't saw my edges.

Now that I know that my graphics drivers work and everything is fine, I tried default booting in ubuntu. Still connected to my desktop display via HDMI it started booting and booted. But the problem was that only desktops display was working. Laptops display was off. So happily I again went into Display settings only to notice that I only get two displays. Desktops and some other with strange unfamiliar name: Chi Mei Optoelectronics corp. 15,6" (I will add screen shots :) ). This other screen was on and should somewhere work but not on laptop. As far as I can remember Laptops screen was always named Built-in Display (in 12.04 and 13.10). And I never had the same problem.

So now I have some questions.
What is the difference between: Ubuntu with Linux 3.11.0-19-generic and 3.13.0-24-generic (I don't know much about Linux as I am new to this stuff. But I know a thing or two about computers.)? Is this different kernels?
Also I want to know if there is important difference between and if it is important which one I use to run ubuntu. Of cours I want to use default one as I don't want to wait every time to ask me. And of course I would be very grateful if anyone will take time and try to help me.

Thank you for your time :)

Ubuntu with Linux 3.11.0-19-generic:

[image]

Default boot:

[image]

P.S. I can't upload images because I don't have reputation 10.

Comment: Your screenshot links are broken.

Comment: Are they working now? I can't upload images because I don't have 10 reputation score.

Comment: Seems like a bug is happening https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1296020?comments=all

Comment: Yeah I noticed multiple users with the same problem. So is there any way to work around this bug or should I wait for update or something? I found some answers here but it is not specific to 14.04 or Intel HD.

Comment: I've searched a lot, and so far the best option is to live with it. And remember to keep using the nouveau driver, the NVidia just makes this problem to get worse.

Comment: 0 down vote
 

I also faced the same problem. While getting rid of the unknown display a weird problem cropped up. The 'unknown display' was in between my 2 displays and when I slid it out, the two displays didn't join together. There was this awkward space in between them. This I guess was the imaginary display. So when I moved my cursor from the left screen towards right, it travelled some imaginary distance before turning up again in my right display.

Comment: Probably it won't help in this case, but you could try to boot Ubuntu adding the `nomodeset` parameter. See if this makes the screen at least show something.

Answer (score 0):

> So I went in System Settings -> Displays and there saw 3 screens.
>   Built-in Display, my secondary desktop display and unknown display.

Probably [bug #1244827](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1244827) "Ubuntu detects a non-existing screen"

> What is the difference between: Ubuntu with Linux 3.11.0-19-generic
>   and 3.13.0-24-generic (I don't know much about Linux as I am new to
>   this stuff. But I know a thing or two about computers.)? Is this
>   different kernels? Also I want to know if there is important
>   difference between and if it is important which one I use to run
>   ubuntu.

Yes, these are different kernels. In general, you should always use the most recent kernel, which is the one with the highest version number. But if there is some bug in the most recent kernel, then feel free to boot an older one if that works.

> So happily I again went into Display settings only to notice that I
>   only get two displays. Desktops and some other with strange unfamiliar
>   name: Chi Mei Optoelectronics corp. 15,6"

The Chi Mei display is your internal laptop screen. You can tell this from the fact that it is the only other screen, and it is 15.6". The fact that it is not being detected as the "Built-in Display" is probably a bug.

I suggest that you download the latest Ubuntu image ([ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso)) and boot from it with your external monitor disconnected. Check whether your internal display works. Then connect the external monitor and enable it in the display settings. This will eliminate the possibility that your problems are being caused by any old config files from Ubuntu 13.10 that are still present on your system.

Comment: I tried that method and the problem is that the screen will not turn on. But I did discover that if I connect my laptop to external screen it will work on that normally but on my laptops screen the backlight will be off. I can see things on my screen but the light is of. And I can't turn it on. It really looks like a bug that only affects me.

Answer (score -1):

Don't know if your problem is same as mine. I had this problem of screen going black whenever totem was launched. I changed the launcher placement to the one which matched with my desktop (mine is Lenovo 20'') and totem then stopped blacking the screen.

Comment: Could you be more specific on how to change totem and what it is? Thank you. P.S. Sorry for late anwser I was away for spring holidays :)

Answer (score -2):

It sounds like a backlight issue. You may try this [fix](http://hacklog.in/acer-aspire-5336-backlight-fix-for-opensuse).