# Is the download live dvd image of Ubuntu up to date?

Tags: updates, live-cd, downloads

Is the live DVD image of Ubuntu on official site of Ubuntu up to date? Because I could not  install Ubuntu 14.04 from live CD because of black screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most probably due to your graphic card. You could try the following, boot up using the live cd and at the Grub menu press "e" to edit the first entry.

[image]

At the end of the Linux kernel entry line add **nomodeset** and press **F10** key. This should boot up Ubuntu with less optimized graphics.

[image]

Comment: When I get home I'll put this to a test. Here is my problem a little better described :) http://askubuntu.com/questions/449801/after-upgrading-from13-10-to-14-04-screen-on-a-laptop-doesnt-work-but

Comment: That sounds more like a backlight issue then. Try this [fix](http://hacklog.in/acer-aspire-5336-backlight-fix-for-opensuse).

Comment: I tried to work with this fix but it is only for openSUSE. I don't have any option to add boot options.

Comment: You need to add the options `acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi=Linux` to the Linux kernel line as shown in the screenshots for Ubuntu, put them instead of `nomodeset`.

Comment: This is how my screen looks like when booting from USB: http://postimg.org/image/e66w6jbvv/ and this is how it looks like after pressing "e": http://postimg.org/image/nincrhb3r/. Where should I put that option line.

Comment: The nomodeset line worked.